# Checking setuptools install_requires on testpypi

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I am trying test a python package I want to release using test `test.pypi`.

In the `setup.py` file I have `install_requires=['numpy>=1.15','scipy>=0.0','scikit-learn>=0.2','numba>=0.0'],`

Scipy and Numpy get downloaded and install as expected.

I get the following error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numba>=0.0`

As a note, if I do `pip install numba` before my test package it will work, but I am trying to make the package work correctly.

I notice when it does the `scipy` requirement first, it shows `Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/72/eb962a3ae2755af6b1f31f7a94dccc21bfc41bb1637c5877a043e711b1d7/scipy-0.1.tar.gz` .

So from the url, it seems like it is using test-files, but is this the regular pypi or just the test one?

My question is: what is the appropriate way to write the `install_requires` so I can make sure the test works before putting it on the actual pypi site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax, it is just that unlike `scipy`, `numpy`, and `scikit-learn`, there is no `numba` hosted on the test PyPI instance.  Compare:

https://pypi.org/project/numba/  <-- 200 OK

https://test.pypi.org/project/numba/   <-- 404 Not Found

*(Note: that 404 was true at the time of writing this answer, but it appears as though a version of numba has now been uploaded to the test index, on [Feb 9th 2021](https://test.pypi.org/project/numba/#history))*

> My question is: what is the appropriate way to write the install_requires so I can make sure the test works before putting it on the actual pypi site?

How you wrote `install_requires` is OK. To smoke test it, by uploading your package to test PyPI and checking that it installs properly, use the test PyPI as an *extra* index url, rather than as a replacement `--index-url`:

```
pip install yourpackage --extra-index-url=https://test.pypi.org/simple/
```

This way `yourpackage` can be found in test PyPI but the install requirements such as `numba` can still be resolved on main PyPI.

Comment: I guess I was thinking the point of test.pypi was to make sure the package worked before putting it on the real one. Is that a misguided understanding or should I not worry so much about putting it on pypi and then having to keep updating it when resolving this part?

Comment: Your understanding was correct - you should get your package working on test PyPI properly first. Do not use main PyPI for experimenting because it is not possible to delete and update a release in-place on main. The error in your original question (can't find `numba`) suggests you're not also looking on main when downloading from test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I spended around 2 hours of my time searching an issue...